# App launching Simple list View - Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am a complete rookie & am developing an app where I want to load the **simple list view** (`using Parse.com`) on click of an image button. I tried `onClickListner` to launch both `MainActivity.java` & `ParseApplication.java` alternatively, but without success. I have even added `MainActivity` to my `AndroidManifest` file.

The app crashes as soon as I click on the image button. Rest other activities are working fine.

Can some one help me with it?

Comment: Can you provide logs?

Comment: post your logs or code for help